# Unikong erases current progress when going to high score menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, unikong

Every third level, Unikong gives you an option to "Continue", "View High Score".  If you click "View high scores", then when you click "return to menu", your progress is not saved. The only option you have is to "Start new game".

Level progression should be saved when you click "View High Score" from the continuation menu.

Comment: And why can't I type in my initials on the high score screen when the game is over instead of having to see "YOU"? As a teen in the 80's there was little more rebellious than entering "ASS" as your initials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah... that seemed like a good idea at the time. To be fair, that time was about 3 in the morning, so that's not saying much.

I have a feeling that the 'high scores' button is going to mysteriously disappear from that screen shortly.